# qmake works in qt-creator but errors out in qt-creator

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to run qt-creator and for some inexplicable reason, when I try to build a project, I receive this error message:

```
Could not start process "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake" /home/user/simple-project/simple-project.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG=qml_debug
```

Yet, when I run qmake with the above arguments, it runs just fine.

To add to this confusion, I have another computer that I tried this on, and qmake actually builds and compiles within qtcreator for this other computer, with no error messages, despite the fact that the configuration is identical to the configuration of the project on the computer that it does not work on.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Both are running within the Windows Subsystem Linux(Ubuntu Trusty) with XMing.

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple qmakes on your system? On the console what does `which qmake` output? Should be the same as in Creator. When you open the “Build & Run” options in Qt Creator are there any errors or warnings on any of the tabs?

Comment: The error message I quoted above `"Could not start process "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake" /home/user/simple-project/simple-project.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64 CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG=qml_debug` is from the compile output tab.  And I was only able to find one version of qt(v.5.2.1) in options->build&run->qt versions on both the computer that successfully builds and compiles and the computer that fails to do so.

Comment: which qmake outputs: /usr/bin/qmake , while the path in qtcreator is /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake.  This is for both the computer with issues and the one without.